# Convert json schema to kotlin data class dynamically

Tags: kotlin, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I have a json schema in draft 04 format (http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#) which is used to define a configuration. These schemas are dynamically created based on use input.

I need to pass this json schema to a method which only accepts a kotlin class as parameter. Is there a way to convert this json schema to a kotlin data class?

Basically what I want is something similar to what [www.jsonschema2pojo.org](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) this does, but I want to create the class dynamically in the method call.

Sample schema:

```
{
    "title": "Schema 1",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "age"]
}
```

Comment: You want to generate a class at runtime, based on a Json?

Comment: Yes as the method I mentioned above accepts class as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at how this IntelliJ Idea plugin does it and use their library in your app: https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass/blob/master/doc/LIBRARY.md

Comment: The blob ref may not work. Here's the shortened link to the repo [JsonToKotlinClass](https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass)